# How to complete generateHash function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

## block.js

In block.js, there is a `generateHash` function. I'm unable to use Promises to calculate the hash asynchronously and update the `hash` property.

```
class Block {

        constructor(data){
            this.id = 0;
            this.nonce = 144444;
            this.body = data;
            this.hash = "";
        }

        generateHash() {
            // Use this to create a temporary reference of the class object
            let self = this;


            //Implement Promises here


        }
    }

    // Exporting the class Block to be reuse in other files
    module.exports.Block = Block;
```

## app.js

In app.js, the `generateHash` function is called and Promises are handled which is pretty clear to me:

```
const BlockClass = require('./block');

/**
 * Creating a block object
 */
const block = new BlockClass.Block("Test Block");

// Generating the block hash
block.generateHash().then((result) => {
    console.log(`Block Hash: ${result.hash}`);
    console.log(`Block: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
}).catch((error) => {console.log(error)});
```

Comment: Why are you "unable to"? Your code is looking great so far, now you just need to add the implementation.  What have you tried so far? If you're getting an error, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write the logic that returns a resolved promise.

```js
class Block {

  constructor(data) {
    this.id = 0;
    this.nonce = 144444;
    this.body = data;
    this.hash = "";

    this.generateHash = this.generateHash.bind(this);
  }

  generateHash() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Implement your hash logic here

      // simulate complex hash calculation
      setTimeout(() => {
        // returning random int(hex) for simplicity
        let hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 << 21)).toString(16);
        this.hash = hash; // save new hash
        resolve(this); // resolve with this block
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
}

// Exporting the class Block to be reuse in other files
// module.exports.Block = Block;

/**
 * Creating a block object
 */
const block = new Block("Test Block");

getHash = async (testBlock) => {
  console.log(`Block[${testBlock.body}]: ${testBlock.hash}`);
  // Generating the block hash
  await testBlock.generateHash()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`Block Hash: ${result.hash}`);
      console.log(`Block: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
  console.log(`Block[${testBlock.body}]: ${testBlock.hash}`);
}

getHash(block);
```